# sorting points by distance to find a path

Tags: r

I want to find the path that connects many points in 2D space (actually latitude, and longitude cords). These points are measured from a train (roughly every 10 seconds).

I found a method to "denoise" the points and reduce the total number of points. Here is an example of how the data looks before I denoise it.

[image]

The data points are not ordered along the path. I would like to do is sort the points along the path so that I can iterate over the points from start to finish.

I'm somewhat new to R. I have written a method to sort the points in C and used Rcpp to integrate my method into R. But I would like know **how I can do this in R**? I don't want to iterate over the points in R in a for loop. That will be too slow. I need something like `sapply` which does the looping internally with a compiled method in R.

Here is an example of the kind of data I have after I denoise (this data is not connect to the plot above).

```
0.000000 0.000000
0.999886 0.015104
1.994528 -0.088276
2.975603 -0.281902
3.945894 -0.523844
4.906713 -0.801021
5.893859 -0.960844
6.864580 -1.201053
7.859816 -1.298548
8.856026 -1.211567
9.851185 -1.113287
10.851147 -1.121947
11.844307 -1.238707
12.800410 -1.531737
13.741038 -1.871177
14.663443 -2.257401
15.641304 -2.466656
16.641061 -2.488718
17.638100 -2.565617
18.633595 -2.660429
19.630684 -2.584182
20.618181 -2.426543
21.595680 -2.215604
22.565897 -1.973365
23.554708 -1.824193
24.508381 -1.523349
25.412466 -1.095996
26.322757 -0.682028
27.216991 -0.234427
28.130066 0.173365
```

In this case it is already sorted. But assume these rows were randomly ordered. **How can I recover the path in order?**

Make the plot like this

```
path <- read.table("data.txt")
plot(path)
lines(path)
```

[image: Points from a path]

Comment: Why do you think a for loop in R would be slow? If written properly, for loops can often be faster than `sapply`

Answer (score 1):

```
path <- read.table(text = "0.000000 0.000000
0.999886 0.015104
1.994528 -0.088276
2.975603 -0.281902
3.945894 -0.523844
4.906713 -0.801021
5.893859 -0.960844
6.864580 -1.201053
7.859816 -1.298548
8.856026 -1.211567
9.851185 -1.113287
10.851147 -1.121947
11.844307 -1.238707
12.800410 -1.531737
13.741038 -1.871177
14.663443 -2.257401
15.641304 -2.466656
16.641061 -2.488718
17.638100 -2.565617
18.633595 -2.660429
19.630684 -2.584182
20.618181 -2.426543
21.595680 -2.215604
22.565897 -1.973365
23.554708 -1.824193
24.508381 -1.523349
25.412466 -1.095996
26.322757 -0.682028
27.216991 -0.234427
28.130066 0.173365")

names(path) <- c("x", "y")

## Randomize points
path <- path[sample(1:nrow(path)),]

## Function to calculate distances
my.dist <- function(p1 = c(x,y), p2 = c(0,0)) sqrt((p1[1]-p2[1])^2 + (p1[2] - p2[2])^2)

dists.to.origin <- apply(path, 1, my.dist)

## Order data frame by distances.
path <- path[order(dists.to.origin),]
plot(path)
lines(path)
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is too simple and does not work in general. Compress the x-axis for example and you will see why after a few iterations. I should have made my question more clear. Nevertheless I have upvoted because I learned a bit from your code. I have a solution using the distance matrix which I will post later.